# "Method links does not exist" with Laravel pagination

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-pagination

I'm passing a collection of posts to my view and I'm trying to use pagination, but I have this error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

**CONTROLLER**

```php
public function index() {
    $posts = Post::where('visible', 1)
        ->where('expire_date', '>', $current)
        ->where('delete', 0)
        ->get();

    return view('search', compact('posts'));
}
```

**VIEW**

```html
<div class="pagination-bar text-center">
       {{ $posts->links() }}
</div>
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change your code to this:

```
$posts = Post::where('visible', 1)
             ->where('expire_date', '>', $current)
             ->where('delete', 0)
             ->paginate(1);

return view('search', compact('posts'));
```

Your code doesn't work because you need to call `paginate()` on the results instead of `get()` or `all()`.