# Method Links doesn't exist. Laravel 5.2

Tags: php, pagination, laravel-5

I'm trying to add paginatio in my views. I have tried following syntax.
Controller:

```
$ads=ads::with('vehicle.Image')->orderBy('views','desc')->paginate(15);
```

Views:

```
<div class="pagination-wrapper ">
    <ul class="pagination pagination-sm">{{ $ads->links() }}</ul>
</div>
```

I cant figure out why it is not working.It throws error of `Method links does not exist` Can anyone tell me what's wrong and how can i make it right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Laravel 5.2 - Method links does not exist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575314/laravel-5-2-method-links-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem in Laravel 5.3 just now. Instead of links() use render(). At some point, links was deprecated.