# Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I created a model relationship between User and Message. I want to implement a list of messages for the authenticated user but I get the following error.

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

**Controller**

```php
public function index()
{
    $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
    $user = User::find($user_id);
    return view('message.index')->with('messages', $user->message);
}
```

**Message provider**

```php
class message extends Model
{
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User');
    }
}
```

**User provider**

```php
public function message ()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Message');
}
```

**index.blade.php**

```php
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('content')
    <h1>messages</h1>
    @if(count($messages)>0)
        @foreach ($messages as $message)
            <div class="well">
                <h3><a href="/message/{{$message->id}}">{{$message->user}}</a></h3>
                <small>Written on {{$message->created_at}} </small>
            </div>
        @endforeach
        {{$messages->links()}}
    @else
        <p> no post found </p>
    @endif
@endsection
```

**Error**

> "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist.(View: C:\xampp\htdocs\basicwebsite\resources\views\message\index.blade.php)"

Comment: The error message looks like you are calling a `links()` method in the `index.blade.php` file. Are you doing this? If not, are you calling `links()` anywhere?

Comment: @GeorgeHanson thanks for the answer but i dont think that i call links i m new with laravel i will share the index.blade view

Comment: It looks like you are calling the `links()` method in your view. You are specifically calling `$messages->links()`. There is no `links()` method on a Laravel Collection, are you trying to do pagination?

Comment: You are calling `links()`. Take a look: `@endforeach
    {{$messages->links()}}
    @else `

Comment: @GeorgeHanson sorry i m new in stackoverflow and i have bad english excuse me but i m trying to show the messages of the user who is loged only his message like on the dashboard

Comment: If you are not using pagination, just remove the line `{{$messages->links()}}` and you should be fine...

Comment: @mare96  thanks a lot it worked when i delete the links i was using those links to show me the message Url according to link but can someone explain to me why it doesn t work when i put the links in this blade page

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laravel 5.2 - Method links does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40575314/laravel-5-2-method-links-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Check your view blade, that method (`links()`) only could be used when your data model is implementing `paginate()` method.

If you dont use `paginate()`, remove this part:

```
{{$messages->links() }}
```

Answer (score 10):

If you are trying to paginate your data when it gets to the view then you need to add the paginate in your controller before passing the data to the view. Example

```
return $users = Users::select('id','name')->paginate(10);
```

with that paginate method in your controller, you can call the links method to paginate your object in view as shown below

```
 {{$users->links()}}
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `{{ $messages->links() }}` in your `index.blade.php` because `{{ $messages->links() }}` is supported only when you use paginate.

Comment: This does not add anything to the previous answers. Please try answering if you have something new to add.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to resolve this issue:

1. Either use paginate function while searching data from database:

   ```
   $users = DB::table('users')->where('id',$user_id)->paginate(1);
   ```
2. Remove `links()` function from `index.blade.php`

   ```
   {{ $messages->links() }}
   ```

Answer (score 0):

In the blade, please insert the below code:

```
{{$messages->links() }}
```

Then, in the controller, insert the below code:

```
return $users = Users::select('name')->paginate(20);
```

Comment: Thank you for your interest in contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This question already has quite a few answers—including one that has been extensively validated by the community. Are you certain your approach hasn’t been given previously? **If so, it would be useful to explain how your approach is different, under what circumstances your approach might be preferred, and/or why you think the previous answers aren’t sufficient.** Can you kindly [edit] your answer to offer an explanation?

Answer (score -1):

You can do something like this in your controller file.

```
    public function index()
    {
        $messages = Message::all()->paginate(5);
        $user_id = auth()->user()->id;
        $user = User::find($user_id);
        return view('message.index')->with('messages', $messages, $user->message);
    }
```

Comment: Does this add value, given the pre-existing answers?