# Laravel, use pagination Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::render does not exist

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to use paginate but it doesn't work, without paginate all are fine but when I use it I get this error
Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist

Controller:

```php
$userorders=Userorder::where('user_id', $user_id)
    ->with('storeinfo')
    ->with('product')
    ->paginate(15)
    ->groupBy('order_number');
```

view:

```html
@if( count($userorders) > 0 )
    {!! $userorders->links() !!}
@endif
```

Comment: `->groupBy()` returns a `Collection`, and collections don't have a `links()` method. (or a `render()` method as your title suggests.) It _might_ work if you switch the order, `[...]->groupBy(...)->paginate();`

Comment: Check This one i think it's same problem https://stackoverflow.com/a/56278462/10066194

Comment: @TimLewis can you explain more please, you mean I have to put paginate after groupby?

Comment: @TimLewis if I do this then I get this error in the blade: Call to a member function product() on boolean

Comment: Like I said, it _might_ work. But that's a different error; what code is producing that?

Comment: You can't group and paginate at the same time unless you do it manually using e.g. a [`LengthAwarePaginator`](https://laravel.com/api/6.x/Illuminate/Contracts/Pagination/LengthAwarePaginator.html)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56278120/method-illuminate-database-eloquent-collectionlinks-does-not-exist)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `links()` is a method of `LengthAwarePaginator`, instead `groupBy` will return a `Collection`, so the only way you can have your UserOrder grouped by its order_number is to switch the order of the calls, to this one

```
$builder= Userorder::where('user_id',$user_id)->with('storeinfo')->with('product');
$userOrdersPagination=$builder->paginate(15);
$userorders=$userOrdersPagination->groupBy('order_number')
```

And then you have to pass to the view also `$userOrdersPagination` and use that to generate the links

Comment: inside blade Im using another forloop if i deleted it then it will work fine but I need it:
  @foreach($groupOrders as $key=>$userorder) 

  {{$userorder->product()->first()->product_name}}, 

  @endforeach

Comment: well in that case you can't do everything in one line of code, try the code on the question, i'll edit now

Comment: can't see? now the code should be 3 lines and also a new line of text under it